# How to find out what redirects the page?

Tags: php, apache, redirect, drupal, drupal-7

I have huge multi domain (Domain Access module is used) Drupal 7 website. It has www sub-domain but when page is visited on www subdomain it's redirected to non-www, main domain.

Problem is that I can't find out what causes that redirection. In some cases it works well, but in some other it doesn't.

I.e. if some pages like:

www.domain.com/de/about_us

is visited user is redirected to:

domain.com/about_us

without that "de" language alias prefix and it results error of course.

I couldn't find it in code nor in .htaccess file. On hoster server there is a plesk "Plesk web pro edition" and under settings for main domain there are settings "Preferred domain" with radio button:

- www.domain.com
- domain.com
- none

And none is selected, so I'm assuming it's not done on host side.

Tried sites for "testing" redirections and all I can find out is that it's 301 type of redirection (temporary one).

Tried Browser devel tools (Chrome, Firebug) but I can't find out anything more that that.

**My question is: is there a way to find out what caused that page redirection?**

Comment: It seems that domains access is doing this weird redirection. Some time ago I had to patch it because image style generation was not working well, but maybe this patch messed up something. Anyway, I added .htaccess redirection and since it happens before the one from Domain Access module the bug is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use phpMyAdmin to search pages in DB:
   go to phpMyAdmin -> select DB -> search -> enter phrase -> select all tables -> search
2. Use application to find redirects on your site:
   https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/integrity/id513610341?mt=12
   https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/broken-link-checker/

Comment: 1. Don't think that url's are stored in DB if that's what you are aiming for. Redirection URL is the same as original one, just www is removed - it's generic.
2. And I don't need to find broken links. I need to find what did that redirection, to turn it off.